# Configuration of Azure CI CD pipeline across two different organizations

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am working on setting up Azure DevOps CI CD pipeline for a project. In this case the git code repo for ASP.NET based application is hosted in Organization B and CI and CD is planned to be executed from Organization A. Both Organization A and Organization B has two separate Azure DevOps Urls. Now in this I am looking to setup CI and CD from Organization A with code repo hosted in Organization B.

Can anyone help me to know what is the best way to deal with this scenario

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops), it depends on whether you use a self hosted Azure DevOps Server, or Azure DevOps services.

Using Azure DevOps server 2020, you can only checkout repositories from the same organization.

In case you are using Azure DevOps services, the documentation provides you with the necessary information, how to implement the checkout from another Azure DevOps organization.